# Want to prevent page reload/leave till Ajax request completion

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a project where I've implemented an AJAX request to store complex data into a database. I want to prevent users from reloading/leaving the page until the AJAX request completes. I've tried adding `async: false` in AJAX but it did not work.

```js
$.ajax({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },
  url: "{{url('api/place-order')}}",
  type: "post",
  async: false,
  data: data,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log("success)
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trying to find a dupetarget for this, and there are dozens of potential matches, but they all have their own little quirk making them not *quite* applicable. (The best one I found, for instance, specifically wanted to do a PUT.) I'm giving up now. :-)

Comment: If user doesn't want to wait and reload, I think you should check and try to improve your performance.

Comment: Well its a long process. it is taking less than 1 sec to return response. I don't think this is a long time. But one of 6000 users he reload the page. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It used to be that *some* browsers allowed synchronous ajax calls, but most don't anymore.

There's an experimental API ([`sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)) that Chrome (perhaps others) recently started supporting that allows you to do an ajax call that will complete even though it **doesn't** hold up closing the page from the user's perspective. But if you really want to hold up closing the page, you just can't do that. But `sendBeacon` could be useful to proactively tell the server the user is (perhaps) going away (as an adjunct to timing it out). ("Perhaps" because of course, they could just be refreshing the page or navigating to another page within the same app/site.)

Comment: in simple words, its not possible?

Comment: Right, you can't. It's driving me **nuts** that I can't remember the name of that experimental API though...

Comment: A possible workaround though, would be to set a boolean flag when the request starts. Then you can check the state of the flag in `beforeunload` and confirm that the user wants to leave the page, noting it will affect data being sent. Then you can reset the flag when the AJAX request completes. Better still, make the request much lighter; have it just send the data to your server then process it later in a background process unrelated to the web server - assuming the user doesn't depend on the result (which I'm guessing they don't if the problem is them closing the browser too early)

Comment: Beacon! That's it. I had to trawl https://www.chromestatus.com/features to jog my memory.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can make some HTML and CSS while the ajax call is going. user may wait until animation complete.something like rounding circle animation .

Comment: I've already done that, but some users do not wait and reload the page.

Comment: you can do something with js when user click on back button but about closing the page , i don't think so.